# Connecting a non-sendable Data Extension to a sendable Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, send-email

I've successfully connected a Non-Sendable Data Extension to a Sendable Data Extension using the primary keys (my Contact ID's).

My problem is that I want to send to the non-sendable Data Extension now that its linked to the Sendable one. How would I go about doing this?

I want to try and avoid doing a vlookup in excel to match the records D':

Comment: By "Connecting", I assume you're referring to Contact Builder Attribute Group relationships? Could you give a bit more information around the nature of your non-sendable data extension, please? Is there a particular reason why the non-sendable data extension cannot be made sendable, if you want to send to it?

Comment: Yes I am. The non-sendable DE is a list of Past User from the last month just contains the customers shop info (eg: address, name etc) the sendable DE contains the contact details of all our Past Users of all time. Both DE's contain the Contact ID which is how i created the data relationship.

I want to send an email to the DE of the Past User from the last month. Because there is a Data relationship between the two DE's I thought then maybe I would then be able to send to them. 

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Overall: You can only send to sendable data extensions.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you would need one of two things:

1) Either create a data relationship inside email studio (subscribers => data relationship), and then create a filtered data extension based on "past users" who have a record in the non-sendable DE (e.g. customer shop info != null), or create a boolean field with default value = true, and filter on that

or

2) Use SQL to generate the audience you need in a new sendable DE. (it can be combined with automation studio and file drops, if it is a process you need to repeat over time).

Linking the data via Contact Builder, like you've done, allows for decision splits inside a journey. That's the primary use case for non-sendable DE's to be linked, to my knowledge :)